# MongoDB Replicaset Connection string using C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, replicaset

I have My Mongo DB set with a replica set of 3. One Primary and Two secondaries.

```
 var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoDBWriteCS"];
 var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
 _MongoWriteServer = client.GetServer();
 _WriteDatabase = _MongoWriteServer.GetDatabase("DBName");
_WriteDatabase.GetCollection<CollectionType>("CollectionName").Insert(Object);
```

When my code runs with the below connection string, it has no issues to insert records

```
<add key="MongoDBWriteCS" value="mongodb://username:password@10.0.0.0:27019/admin?w=0" />
```

But the problem is, since it is on replica set, my primary keeps changing when primary goes from 27019 to 27018 or 27017 inserts fails.

So I tried to change my connection string as more authentic Replica set connection string.

```
<add key="MongoDBWriteCS" value="mongodb://username:password@10.0.0.0:27017,10.0.0.0:27018,10.0.0.0:27019/admin?replicaSet=myRepSet&amp;readPreference=primaryPreferred&amp;w=0" />
```

It keeps failing with "**No such host**" or "**unable to connect to a member**",but with in the same line of code get list of collections works (I mean reads works only writes fails like insert or save commands)

I am using **MongoDB 2.6.4**

**rs.status()**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "set" : "rbRepSet",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-03-09T23:27:17.000Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "haboMongo:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 59570,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1425941592, 5),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T22:53:12.000Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-03-09T23:27:16.000Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-03-09T23:27:17.000Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "syncingTo" : "haboMongo:27019"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "haboMongo:27018",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 2220179,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1425941592, 5),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T22:53:12.000Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-03-09T23:27:17.000Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-03-09T23:27:16.000Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "syncingTo" : "haboMongo:27019"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "haboMongo:27019",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 2220202,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1425941592, 5),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T22:53:12.000Z"),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1425100988, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2015-02-28T05:23:08.000Z"),
            "self" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**rs.config()**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : "rbRepSet",
    "version" : 3,
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "haboMongo:27017"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "haboMongo:27018"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "haboMongo:27019"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem from your brief description " my primary keeps changing when primary goes from 27019 to 27018 or 27017 inserts fails", but, unless itt's a copy/paste problem, you have &amp;'s in your connection uri instead of &

Comment: We need to see your replica set config. Could you post the results of this from the shell?

rs.config();

Comment: @CraigWilson added the config info

Comment: So, even though you are connecting with IP addresses, we actually will connect with the hostnames as configured. Can you verify that you can resolve each of those hostnames from your client machine?

Comment: Yes. I confirm. Because it works when I give my connection string as <add key="MongoDBWriteCS" value="mongodb://username:password@10.0.0.0:27019/admin?w=0" /> and other two ports as well

Comment: I don't think I was clear. Can you connect when you use this app setting, where the connection string includes the dns name and not the IP address.

<add key="MongoDBWriteCS" value="mongodb://username:password@haboMongo:27019/admin?w=0" />

Comment: @CraigWilson no not with haboMongo:27019, since my IIS and Mongo are on two different servers. So I use IP and resolve the IP (10.0.0.0:27019) to haboMongo:27019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have used hostnames in your replica set configuration, the driver will discover those hostnames and use them instead of the ip addresses in your connection string. Therefore, your hostnames MUST be resolvable by your client box. I'd recommend you use hostnames, but if for some reason you can't, then you'll need to put IP addresses into your replica set config.

Comment: I'd be surprised that it actually does on a long-running basis. You might see a bit of success right at the beginning of your program (where the insert is), and then it will start to fail shortly after.

Comment: IPs keep changing right. isn't this the right way to keep it like a name and resolve the IP to this name?

Comment: Yes, the best thing to do would be to use hostnames, in both your connection string AND in your replica set config. But those hostnames have to be resolvable from your client. As you said, they currently aren't which is why you are having issues.

Comment: will give it a try and see if that would fix it. But again i don't understand why does it work perfectly if my connection string is not for replica set.

Comment: It works fine if the connection string isn't for a replica set because when there isn't a replica set, there isn't a replica set config for us to use. Hence, the only source of data when not using a replica set is the connection string.

Comment: You were right. That was it. changed host names to public domain and updated the connection string and so far working good.